# Answers don't update correctly when the question is open

Tags: bug, notifications, android-app

In the Android app, if a question is open and a notification of a new answer is received, tapping the notification sends me back to the question without the new answer.

If a new answer notification is received, the current in-memory copy of the question should be trashed and retrieved anew.

Comment: Related: I experienced a similar bug on the site as well. Sometimes when I click the `N new answer(s)` notification, it disappears, but the answer doesn't appear. I have to refresh the question in the browser.

Comment: Hello, this is a test comment.